# Move a vertex programmatically from Python

Tags: python, edit-mode, vertices

I am trying to move vertices programmatically, but whatever I do, there is no effect.
I am using this simple script on the default cube in Blender 2.93 (for use with luxCore)

```
import bpy

# Get the active object and its mesh data
obj = bpy.context.active_object
print(obj)
mesh = obj.data

# Ensure object mode and vertex selection mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")

# Select the vertex you want to move (for example, the first vertex)
vertex_index = 0
mesh.vertices[vertex_index].select = True
print(mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co)
# Set the new coordinates for the selected vertex
new_coordinates = (1.2, 1.2, 1.2)  # Set your desired coordinates here
mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co = new_coordinates

# Update the mesh to reflect the changes
mesh.update()
print(mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co)
# Optionally, switch back to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

However, when running the script twice, the console output looks as:

```
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube") at 0x7fc7e3ef0008>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.2000, 1.2000, 1.2000)>
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube") at 0x7fc7e3ef0008>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.2000, 1.2000, 1.2000)>
```

As you can see, the original vertex position is 1,1,1, and the script moves it to 1.2,1.2,1.2.  But the object does not change in the scene, and when simply running again, the vertex coordinates are again 1,1,1.

Any idea what is missing here?

Comment: do it in object mode

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to switch to edit mode as you're directly modifying mesh data, with no use of `bpy.ops`.

Instead ensure you're in object mode from the begining.

I've removed unneeded parts and commented below:

```
import bpy

# Get the active object and its mesh data
obj = bpy.context.active_object
print(obj)
mesh = obj.data

# Don't do that as you're not using bpy.ops
# Ensure object mode and vertex selection mode
#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
#bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Select the vertex you want to move (for example, the first vertex)
vertex_index = 0

# Unneeded for the same reason
#mesh.vertices[vertex_index].select = True
print(mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co)

# Set the new coordinates for the selected vertex
new_coordinates = (1.2, 1.2, 1.2)  # Set your desired coordinates here
mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co = new_coordinates

# Unneeded
# Update the mesh to reflect the changes
#mesh.update()

print(mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co)
```

Manipulating object data directly is not allowed in edit mode, except using `bmesh` module ([see here](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/bmesh.html) for 2.93 version).

Comment: I think you want to move the last line to the beginning to ensure the object mode is set all along

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, personally, no... ;)... but  you're right, I'll indicate that.

Comment: Works like a charm, thx!  It's sometimes quite confusing which mode to use when in blender...